# Creating a looped HTML element in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm relatively new to React, I've looked a lot of places and can't find a way to specifically handle this. I have checked previous answers.

I am trying to get my application to loop through an array and also print a statement along with the array.

```
var user = ["Kevin", "Kyle", "Kylian"];

var Hello = <h1>
            Hello, {user}!
            </h1>

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    for(var i=0;i<user.length;i++){
    return Hello;
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

Output:

`Hello, KevinKyleKylian!`

Expected Output:

```
Hello, Kevin!
Hello, Kyle!
Hello, Kylian!
```

As you can see, the loop for some reason doesn't continuously return the entire output and after the user iteration of {user} it just prints {user} until the array is ended. Why does this happen? How can I avoid this?

Comment: I've also tried return `<h1> Hello, {user[i]} </h1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of this bit:

```
var Hello = <h1>
            Hello, {user}!
            </h1>
```

In that case 'user' is referring to the whole array, not just a specific element of that array.

Generally, if you're building elements dynamically in React it's good to put that in a separate function rather than the render method, I feel it's a bit neater. So something like this:

```
getUsers() {
  let userList = [];
  for (let i=0; i<user.length; i++) {
    userList.push(<div>Hello, {user[i]}</div>);
  }
  return userList;
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      {this.getUsers()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, this worked. I had to change `render() {
  return(
    <div>
      this.getUsers();
    </div>
  );
}` 


to 
`render() {
  return(
    <div>
      {this.getUsers()};
    </div>
  );
}`

Comment: React is difficult, I'm relatively new and it's just a lot to learn all at once! I did the entire CodeAcademy course and didn't learn a thing. So now I'm doing it again and building an app along side of it as I learn to have a more practical grasp of it.

Comment: Yeah React is hard to learn initially, but once things start to click it's super fun and much easier. Just gotta get over that initial learning hump

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I think what is most confusing is transitioning from JS to JSX and then also incorporating the React commands as well. Cheers!